# Issue uploading public images to AWS S3 Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-9

I have searched widely for this problem but to no avail. Here's the code that's giving me the issue.

```php
 if ($request->hasFile("images")) {
    foreach ($request->file("images") as $i => $image) {
        $path = $image->storePubliclyAs($product->id, "image_$i.{$image->extension()}");

    }
}
```

The line with `$image->storePubliclyAs()` is raising the error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Found 1 error while validating the input provided for the GetObject operation:
[Key] expected string length to be &gt;= 1, but found string length of 0 in file /var/www/html/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Api/Validator.php on line 65
```

I should note that I've already indicated in the `.env` file that the filesystem disk should be pointed to S3. The bucket's objects are also entirely public. This is quite confusing as `$image->storeAs()` works perfectly fine.

Comment: can you check if `$image` is not empty and  also contains `extension`?

Comment: @Win they're defined properly. `extension` does exist.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround. Instead of using the `storePubliclyAs()` method, just use `storeAs()` and `Storage::setVisibility()` respectively:

```php
if ($request->hasFile("images")) {
    foreach ($request->file("images") as $i => $image) {
        $path = $image->storeAs($product->id, "image_$i.{$image->extension()}");
        Storage::setVisibility($path, "public");
    }
}
```

Kind of weird but it's been the only way I could get it to work.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this code below. I just changed how you are using $i in giving the image a name.

```
 if ($request->hasFile("images")) {
    foreach ($request->file("images") as $i => $image) {
        $path = $image->storePubliclyAs($product->id, "image_".$i.{$image->extension()}");

    }
}
```

Comment: i think this will also not work , file name now will become `"image_1png"` instead of intended by sender `"image_1.png"` , notice the missing dot before extension